# How to unset all custom QStyledItemDelegates from QListView?

Tags: qt, qlistview, qstyleditemdelegate

I set a few custom delegates in my list. When I do a reset of the model `QListView::reset();` gets called but the delegates are not reset. Is this a bug, if not how can I reset all delegates?

Iterating over all rows and set the delegates to `nullptr` would work but is not a proper solution.

Comment: How do you set a delegates? Can we see some code? `QListView::reset` - is not resetting a model. Delegates are not related you your model at all. Possible you are misunderstanding Qt MVC.

Comment: setItemDelegateForRow(i, _selectedDelegate);

Comment: Do you really need different delegates for all rows? Solution: connect to a `modelAboutToBeReset` slot and perform cleaning of delegates there.

Answer (score 0):

Qt [internally maintains](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/9d9b7f53750dce2da88d7d11d312b4b36250b5c5:src/gui/itemviews/qabstractitemview_p.h#L342) an map of the custom row delegates but does not give acces to it. I ended up maintaining a list myself and unset them all if I need to using

`void QAbstractItemView::setItemDelegateForRow(int row, QAbstractItemDelegate * delegate)`

with a `nullptr` as delegate;